# How to tune / analyze the performance of MySQL queries run in parallel (from different requests)?

Tags: mysql, innodb, amazon-rds

I am using Mysql.

- Environment : aws rds, m4.large, (2cpu, 8GB memory, 100GB disk), InnoDB

The situation happened, when I sent queries simultaneously to the database.

Normally, when I request alone it took around 0.5seconds. However, when I request two queries at the same time, response times are doubled for both.(1.0~)

First time, I thought it was my query problem or database architecture problem(like indexing or something)

Even though, I sent two simple query (which are following indexing), response times are doubled also.(It was quite difficult to send 10's ms query at the same time)

I also concerned about the locking, but when I tested it, there was no insert query.

Is this database problem? or OS problem? 
Is there anyone who have these kind of situation?

Comment: This question lacks detail.

Comment: I'm sorry @Drew Is there anything that you want more?

Comment: The schemas ... so that would be the output from `show create table xyz` for every table xyz related to this problem. And the queries you are running. The output from `explain` too.

Comment: There are a dozen possible answers; let's focus on your particular query.